# Resolving object dependencies on client using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-ng-repeat, spring-data, restangular

I have problems with restoring my entity relations at the (AngularJS) client after retrieving them via REST using Restangular. I searched a lot, but could not find a clean solution. I have some years of programming experience, but I'm quite new to the AngularJS ecosphere and the REST paradigm.

## The task

At my Spring Data backend I have two entities, `Article` and `ArticleGroup`, in a 1:n relationship. The resulting REST json (via Spring Data Rest) looks like this:

**Article**

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A Drink",
            "price": 2.90,
            "created": null,
            "modified": null,
            "active": false,
            "displayOrder": 0,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/articles/1"
                },
                "articleGroup": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/articles/1/articleGroup"
                }
            }
        },
      ...
```

**ArticleGroup**

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "articleGroups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Drinks",
            "printer": null,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/articleGroups/1"
                },
                "articles": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/articleGroups/1/articles"
                }
            }
        },
      ...
```

Now I want to display a tabgroup containing the articleGroup.name as the tab's label and a table of the articles in this articleGroup as its content:

```
<tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="group in articleGroups" heading="{{group.name}}">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="article in group.articles">
                    <td ng-click="increase(article)">{{article.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.price | currency }}</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tab>
</tabset>
```

I retrieve the articleGroups easily in my AngularJS controller using Restangular:

```
Restangular.all('articleGroups').getList()
        .then(function(groups) {
            $scope.articleGroups = groups;
        });
```

This works fine and the tabs show up nicely. Now I can do so for the articles as well, but here I come upon the problem which I'm dealing with for days now.

## The problem

**How can I filter the articles for their articleGroup so every portion of articles appears in the right tab?** What is the right expression in the ng-repeat above where I just put "group.articles" as a placeholder now?
This sounds very easy, but my problem is that I have no operational identification of an Article's articleGroup to filter the right articles in the ng-repeat for each tab. What I tried:

- using the self.href as an id à la `article._links.articleGroup.href == articleGroup._links.self.href`, but this doesn't work as you can see in the JSON above those two links are set up differently
- adding (database) ids to the JSON, but of course an article does not contain the id of its articleGroup, but only the link relation
- looping through articleGroups and retrieving each group's articles into an array with the articleGroup.id as the key, but I can't get this to work out as I either get `undefined` errors by JavaScript or infinite loops

## Help

Before I continue fiddling along for hours, it would be great if you could give me hints on which direction to take and what a "clean" and methodologically sound approach to the task would be. How can I bring articles and their corresponding group back togehter?
It seems like such an easy (and frequent) problem, but I tried for hours and days to get it running and fear I'm missing something. I looked at many examples but none of them helped me to have a breakthrough.
I'm happy to provide any further information as needed. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it. It turned out that I got lost in the handling of asynchronous requests, especially between having a data object itself and a promise for a request, i.e. placeholders which provide access to the data as soon as it is available - very well explained in [this post](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/).

Restangular always returns promises. So I came up with the following solution which works exactly as I wanted to:

For the controller code:

```
Restangular.all('articleGroups').getList()
        .then(function(groups) {
            $scope.articleGroups = groups;
            for(i=0;i<groups.length;i++) {
                $scope.articles[groups[i].id] = groups[i].getList("articles")
            }
        });
```

So when the articleGroups arrive from the server, I walk through all of them and put them into the array `$scope.articles` with the `articleGroup.id` as key. Notice that `group[i].getList("articles")` returns a promise for the articles relation. With Restangular's $object property, I receive the articles data array in the `ng-repeat`:

```
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="group in articleGroups" heading="{{group.name}}">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="article in articles[group.id].$object | orderBy:'id':false ">
                    <td>{{article.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.price | currency }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

Now, all articles of the selected `articleGroup`'s tab are displayed on the tab. While this seems fine, I'm still not sure if this is the best solution in terms of style or performance. But at least it's a step ahead. Comments very welcome.